# How do I get Synapse to search my Tomboy notes?

Tags: tomboy, zeitgeist, synapse

In this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/683550 it says 
"Tomboy has a dataprovider for Zeitgeist, so if you have that Tomboy notes should be easily searchable using Synapse"

I've got the Zeitgeist PPA from here: https://launchpad.net/~zeitgeist/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=maverick. I installed the package zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy, but still cannot get tomboy notes in Synapse's search results. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the person who developed `zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy`. Due to tomboy note format you can only search by the title of the Note and not by the contents.

This is a limitation because for that the whole content of the note has to be stored as an event. (Actually it can be, but doesn't make much sense to fill the database with content already present in Notes)

Try searching by Note Title, if it doesn't work then I can look further.

---

If you have not enabled this plugin, then please goto Tomboy preferences, and check `Zeitgeist Dataprovider`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Searching note title would be great, but I am not even able to do that. I don't think my notes are being logged at all. My version of zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy is: 0.1.0+bzr20100127-0ubuntu1~maverick1~ppa2 (zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy). I see it as enabled in the software centre. And I have enabled Zeitgeist in Synapse. What else should I be doing?

Comment: Did you enable this plugin in Tomboy preferences?

Comment: That's it! I had not realised this was a tomboy plugin. Thank you!!

Comment: What if Zeitgeist Dataprovider is not available as a plugin to activate? Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: as R3s3t notes, this no longer works in 11.04: it looks like the package zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy is not available for Natty.

Comment: Yes. This package is actually not available for Natty and Oneiric. I was supposed to release v0.8 of datasources, but since I am on the move, I am not able to do it. I will ask someone else from Zeitgeist team to get the release and package it

Comment: @Manisha Sinha: that would be wunderbar

Comment: zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy is now available for Natty

Comment: @geoffrey : Thanks for updating. Yeah I uploaded it to PPA 5 days back. Everyone should have got it if they did an update. Make sure zeitgeist 0.8, zeitgeist-sharp 0.8 and then zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy are all 0.8

Comment: I installed the packages from the ppa, installed the tomboy datasource plugin and enabled it, rebooted. But still, Synapse won't parse any of the tomboy titles. If I open a Tomboy note via Tomboy it will show up in Synapse giving the title and the location: note://title//somenumbers. Trying to open it via Synapse fails with the output: [UtilsLogger] The specified location is not supported

In summary: Parsing of Tomboy notes does not work even with the zeitgeist plugin enabled in Tomboy

Comment: Does it work for anybody?

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with Synapse. Are you using Synapse from this PPA? https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ppa Or you can try out the bleeding edge https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/testing (You can downgrade to stable one if the issue if not solved)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete how-to (works in Oneiric):

1. Open a terminal and write: 
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeitgeist/ppa 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install zeitgeist-datasource-tomboy
2. Restart your computer (maybe restarting Tomboy is enough, I did not check).
3. Open Tomboy Preferences, Add-ins tab. Choose Logging category, and enable Zeitgeist Dataprovider Add-in.
4. Every note you open from now on will appear in the Synapse results box.