# Can I search tomboy notes with dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search, tomboy, notes

With gnome-do I could! It's very very useful for me, because tomboy is well integrated in Ubuntu. Why doesn't dash have anything about this?

Answer (score 7):

I've written a small Lens for Unity, allowing to search and open Tomboy notes.

You'll find it here:

https://launchpad.net/~remi.rerolle/+archive/unity-lens-tomboy

Please let me know if you find it useful or have any comments/problems.

**To install:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-tomboy
```

Source -> [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/search-through-your-tomboy-notes-with-unity-tomboy-lens/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20d0od%20%28OMG!%20Ubuntu!%29)

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: Any chance to make this avail for 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, no.

This question is related to a question I asked: [How do I get Synapse to search my Tomboy notes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/32161/8116) -- because both dash and synapse use zeitgeist. I am now able to search my notes with synapse, but for some reason not with the dash. I am not a developer, so can't say why not, but it is probably trivial enough to get Dash to show the tomboy notes logged by zeitgeist.

However, even if tomboy notes are logged by zeitgeist, this will not replace gnome-do: gnome-do searches through all your notes, whereas zeitgeist only logs the notes you open. I still rely on gnome-do just to search my notes.

I have posted a question that might bring us an answer: [Tomboy notes logged by zeitgeist do not appear in the Unity dash. Why not?](https://askubuntu.com/q/49488/8116)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Tomboy lens that was available in 11.10 doesn't work with 12.04.
Fortunately, Tomboy notes can easily be searched using the HUD: press 'Alt' + a keyword or title of yor note... et voilà!

Comment: this only seems to work for the 10 last edited notes that are available in the drop down menu of the indicator, so not very useful.

Comment: A neat find, but too bad you can't search all the notes...

Comment: You're right. This and Ubuntu One having stopped syncing Tomboy notes made me switch to Evernote and Everpad, which comes with it's own Unity lens.