# Tomboy notes logged by zeitgeist do not appear in the Unity dash. Why not?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, tomboy, zeitgeist

I am able to search my Tomboy notes using Synapse (and using a zeitgeist plugin), after following the instructions here: 
[How do I get Synapse to search my Tomboy notes?](https://askubuntu.com/q/32161/8116) My notes also appear in the Activity Journal.

Since both Synapse and the Dash rely on Zeitgeist data, why don't Tomboy notes also appear in the Unity Dash search results? Is there anything that can be done? (A similar question has been asked: [Can I search tomboy notes with dash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48871/8116))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Tomboy Unity lens that enables one to search through Tomboy notes in the dash. To install, open a terminal and add the appropriate ppa to your software sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:remi.rerolle/unity-lens-tomboy
```

Then update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-tomboy
```

You might need to log out and back in to get the search functionality.

More information here: https://launchpad.net/~remi.rerolle/+archive/unity-lens-tomboy

Comment: This will not work on Ubuntu 12.04...unfortunately